# Can a term be both deictic and cataphoric?

Tags: pragmatics

In a sentence like "Will you, Maria?" where there is cataphora, can you be both deictic and cataphoric? In general, can a term be both anaphoric and deictic?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, depending on what it means for "a term to be both anaphoric and deictic". `You` is both referring to a context-specific thing (deictic) and also refers to a term that appears later in the sentence (cataphoric).

It could reasonably be thought that `you` carries a `[+deictic]` property since any sentence with `you` will necessarily reference something in the context. However, `you` does not seem to carry a `[+cataphoric]` property since `you` can come in a sentence where there is no cataphora.

- You are smart.

In the above sentence, there is no cataphora since `you` does not refer to any term/phrase that appears later in the sentence. Cataphora seems to be a relationship between terms in a sentence, and thus the term itself is not cataphoric.